# C# .NET DocX inserting captions to an Image

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, docx

Is there a way to insert captions to image just like MS word allows you to insert caption when right clicking an image? The problem is the existing caption support differs with the right-click method in a way that the figure number is not updated. I want to do it in the exact same way such that figure number is also appended with the caption by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing research for about 2 days I found a way myself to insert Caption in Word exactly like "Insert Caption" option when we right click an image or a table.
Actually in MS Word the figure or table numbers are **Document Fields**. Yes that might sound a bit new but these field are there and can be viewed by right clicking any inserted caption in the document and clicking **Toggle Field Codes**. One can say these are actually formulas that represent different meaning. For instance the `{SEQ}` means initializing a sequence that starts from 1.

Ok that was enough on what actually is caption. In short we need to insert a "Document Field" with a formula to insert caption to images.

Actually this can be implemented in Xceed Opensource library by using the **Simple Fields**. Simple Fields are a exact replica of Document fields. And the Xceed examples uses simple for the implementation of adding page number to the document in its HeaderFooter example.
I have implemented my function that is similar to the `AppendPageNumber(PageNumberFormat pnf)` function.
You can use this for the implementation of captions in the `Paragraph.cs`

```
public Paragraph InsertNumberedSequence()
{
  XElement fldSimple = new XElement( XName.Get( "fldSimple", Document.w.NamespaceName ) );
  fldSimple.Add( new XAttribute( XName.Get( "instr", Document.w.NamespaceName ), @"SEQ " ) );
  
  XElement content = XElement.Parse
  (
   @"<w:r w:rsidR='001D0226' xmlns:w=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"">
               <w:rPr>
                   <w:noProof /> 
               </w:rPr>
               <w:t>1</w:t> 
           </w:r>"
  );

  fldSimple.Add( content );
  Xml.Add( fldSimple );

  return this;
}
```

And for adding caption one can use

```
document.InsertParagraph($"captionLabel ").InsertNumberedSequence().Append(" my caption text");
```